# задержка цикла for внутри цикла while

Tags: python

Мне нужно сделать так чтобы выделенный на картинке цикл for имел кд(задержку) 1 секунду перед повторным выполнением, но при этом мне нельзя останавливать общий цикл While.
Я пробовал реализовать это используя asyncio, но дело в том что мне нельзя вытаскивать этот цикл for за рамки цикла while.

[image: Code]

Comment: Это невозможно. Цикл while перейдет к следующей итерации, только после того как цикл for отработает полностью.  Есть ли какая-то причина, почему этот for нельзя вынести за рамки while?

Comment: он задействует переменные cx и cy которые обрабатываются внутри цикла while

Comment: а в чем проблема передавать эти данные наружу?

Comment: я передаю их в Лист (joints_position) где находятся 21 разные значения cy и cx, я пытался вынести их в отдельный while но все тщетно,

Comment: я думаю вам стоит изучить основы программирования, прежде чем начать трогать CV.
почитайте про асинхронность, мультипроцессы, отдельные потоки

Comment: вот я и изучаю asyncio, пытаясь создать отдельный процесс, для запуска этих циклов параллельно, я надеялся что это можно решить каким либо другим путем

Comment: для отдельных процессов существует multiprocessing, а asycio нужен для асинхронного выполнения кода

Comment: спасибо, ознакомлюсь

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то тебе нужно сделать так, чтобы for работал только каждую секунду, но нельзя его перемещать за цикл. Можно использовать проверку на время.
За циклом создаём настоящее время с помощью библиотеки time, а потом сверяем время так, чтобы переменная была меньше настоящего времени на одну секунду. Пример:

```
import time
Time = time.time()
Sum = 0
while True:
    Sum += 1
    if Time <= time.time() - 1:
        Time = time.time()
        print(f"За секунду прошло {Sum} циклов.")
        Sum = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Как было упомянуто в комментариях нельзя остановить for при этом что бы while работал непрерывно. Ты можешь обернуть for в асинхроную функцию, передавать ей значения, и внутри прописать await. Тем самым будет обещание выполниться через нужное время. Но while будет тебе плодить новые функции и у тебя будет умножаться очередь эвейтов что скорей всего крашнется через пару часов. По этому while тоже надо ставить на паузу.